# How to share data between Service Project (WCF) and another project

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

(Edited) -> I have a solution with different projects. It has a strange structure because I'm not an professional software engineer. The solution has three parts: one HMI project (WPF), bussiness project (class library type) and service project (WCF).

In the bussiness project, I do some process that has result which I save in a static class. This results are exposed in the screen by WPF project mentioned previously and now I need to transfer this data by one service placed in the WCF project.

The object is similar to:

```
[DataContract]
public class ObjectToTransfer
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ParameterOne = string.Empty;
    [DataMember]
    public string ParameterTwo = string.Empty;
}
```

In the other hand, the method that picks up the informtion from static class belonging to bussiness project is like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior]
public class Service: IService
{
    public ObjectToTransfer SendObject()
    {
    return new ObjectToTransfer{
      ParameterOne = BusinessProject.StaticClass.ResultOne,
      ParameterTwo = BusinessProject.StaticClass.ResultTwo
    };
}
```

Well, when I consume the service the result is a object with the parameters one and two empty. In additon, when I debug the solution with both projects run, the static class hasn't info in her atributes... It's like whether both projects run independently, in spite of both are under the same solutions..., It's like whether there was no relationship between them. Where is the mistake?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Static objects live once per AppDomain. Anyway read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Comment: WCF is referred as Service Refernce in WPF project. Just below the usual Reference.

Comment: I don't understand your comment Kay Lee ...

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you will need to do is change the `DataContract` class to a class with proper getters and setters.

```
[DataContract]
public class ObjectToTransfer
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ParameterOne { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ParameterTwo { get; set; }
}
```

The reason this is important is because of the way WCF works when it try to serialize the data from the server to the client. Essentially, the class on the server side schematically matches a generated class on the client. (They share the same class schema.) If there is no proper structure to the class, the data cannot get set. The members are basically read-only.

What you have in your class right now are public member variables, and they are set to always return `string.Empty`. WCF can't work with that, it is too strict. The server and the client need to be able to read and write to all `DataMember` properties, so you need the `{ get; set; }`.

Don't forget to refresh your service reference after making this change.

If you need some good resources to learn WCF, check out these videos [WCF Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVxEyaRMaMN_-qnDdNVGsL1). They are a little dated, but all of the concepts still apply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem... I can't read a static class from my WCF Service Project independently of setters and getters

Answer (score 0):

This might be  late and I am new to WCF service, so I am sharing based on what I have done in my case to share data among different projects.

#### Background of my project:

I have a WCF service(host), a client and a server project. (A total of 3 different projects.) I will perform the necessary calculation in WCF service. Afterwards, I am suppose to share the result to the client and server. Therefore, there is this variable, variableA, that I have share among the 3 projects.

#### What I did:

In WCF service, I declare `variableA` and mark it `static`:

```
private **static** string variableA;
```

Only after I marked `variableA` as static, then I can see the same `variableA` across different projects.

I am not sure if this helps but this is what I did in my case.